# Rails - Caught SIGTERM, shutting down on AWS EC2 running on Apache Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I get this error when I make some changes in my app. Previously it works well until i pushed the last code. I made a lot of changes in my file so that i can not track which one is causing this error.

I haved tried to search at other threads but i could not find solution that can solve my problem. This problem is similar to other threads that have been discussed few times here but only few people interested to post any solutions.

Please can someone shared their experience on this?

This error can be found in **/var/log/apache2/error.log**

mpm_event:notice] [pid 14458:tid 140091015935872] **AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down**
[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.7713 14759/7fb04324c780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.46', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.46', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.46', 'web_server_pid' => '14758', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }

[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.7759 14762/7f11d7132780 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:649 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.14758/generation-0/request
[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.7825 14767/7f1165b73780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.14758/generation-0/logging
[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.7829 14759/7fb04324c780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.7914 14782/7f938c30f780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.46', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.46', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.46', 'web_server_pid' => '14779', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }

[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.7958 14785/7f3da825f780 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:649 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.14779/generation-0/request
[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.8019 14790/7fcd26fe4780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.14779/generation-0/logging
[Mon Oct 13 09:48:43.802685 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14779:tid 140057092278144] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.46 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 13 09:48:43.802751 2014] [core:notice] [pid 14779:tid 140057092278144] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ 2014-10-13 09:48:43.8053 14782/7f938c30f780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check your configurations. This problem may be because you set your config.force_ssl equal to true. Change it back to false then restart your server using sudo service apache2 restart.

Comment: it works for me!! after i commented out that, it works great

Comment: Even if my app is in Python, I found exactly this reason was causing that weird error...